# GCM without a activity

Tags: android, class, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using php mysql and android to notify users when something happens. But i dont need a ui. So is it possible to do GCM without putting all your code on a activity?

Comment: You could extend the GCMBaseIntentService, which will be a background service that runs without the UI. You could probably fire a notification from there.

Comment: This is a really nice example of using GCM for push notifications. Check the GCMBaseIntentService class here : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/#highlighter_736573 .

Comment: GCMBaseIntentService is depricated in API 23, you need to import a lib to use this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, GCM is not dependent on a UI in anyway.  You can do the gcm registration code where ever makes sense for your app and handle the messages in a service.  Typically this is done by extending GcmListenerService.  Then you can do whatever you would like from there.